# Highcharts: closest point on chart gets highlights and shows tooltip instead of the point where mouse in pointing

Tags: highcharts

I am running into an issue of incorrect point's tooltip on synchronised charts. On the synchronised charts the crosshair is shown and using `ordinal:false` I am plotting equidistance ticks.

The issue occurs when the crosshair moves along with mouse-move and shows the nearest point's data on the tooltip.

The expected behaviour is: when there is no data, crosshair should be shown but not the tooltip.

here is an existing SO fiddle I found https://jsfiddle.net/jknipp/g3vr5v44/13/

[image: ScreenShot illustrate the issue]

Comment: There is a lot going on in that fiddle, the parameters that control  what you are after is already set as well, namely: [snap](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.snap), and [stickyTracking](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.stickyTracking) and [shared tooltips](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.shared). That said, if no combination of those options yeilds results, you might need to change how shared tooltips behave by [wraping](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) the function that shows tooltips

Comment: The issue is that the chart tries to find the closest point and shows the tooltip. I want to show tooltip on exact point only.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the effect you need, just return `false` if `window.isOutOfSync`, instead of `No data` string here:

```
formatter: function(tooltip) {
          var header,
            s = [];

          console.log(window.isOutOfSync);
          if (window.isOutOfSync) {
            console.log("don't show tooltip");
            //return false;
            console.log(this)
            return false;
          }

          $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {

            // check to see if the point is in the overall graph
            //var overallChart = $("#total_success_rates").highcharts();
            //console.log(overallChart);

            var isSuccessRate = (point.series.name == 'Success');

            if (header == null) {
              var config = point.point.getLabelConfig();
              header = tooltip.tooltipFooterHeaderFormatter(config);
            }
            s.push(formatSuccessRateToolTip(point.y, isSuccessRate));
            // $("#" + point.series.name.toLowerCase() + "-rate").html(point.y + "%");
          });

          return header + s.reverse().join('<br>');
        }
```

**[EDIT]**

Additionally, please call `reflow()` inside of the `chart.events.load` function on both charts, just like below:

```
  chart: {
    renderTo: container,
    type: 'areaspline',
    events: {
        load() {
        this.reflow()
      }
    },
    height: '220',
    spacingBottom: 20,
    spacingTop: 20,
    spacingLeft: 20,
    spacingRight: 20
  },
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/27veyw1d/

Comment: I want to avoid choosing of nearest point. when you hover on the chart and if data-point not there, it selects the nearest point available and highlights that point.